# Tor bundle error circuit_remove_handled_ports(): Port 443 is not handled

Tags: tor

When I start Tor bundle on Ubuntu 18.04 I get an error:

```
Jul 11 11:25:05.000 [debug] command_process_destroy_cell(): Received for circID 3910604357.
Jul 11 11:25:05.000 [info] circuit_mark_for_close_(): Circuit 0 (id: 37) marked for close at ../src/core/or/command.c:654 (orig reason: 517, new reason: 0)
Jul 11 11:25:05.000 [debug] connection_or_process_cells_from_inbuf(): 13: starting, inbuf_datalen 0 (0 pending in tls object).
Jul 11 11:25:05.000 [debug] circuit_increment_failure_count(): n_circuit_failures now 6.
Jul 11 11:25:05.000 [info] circuit_free_(): Circuit 0 (id: 37) has been freed.
Jul 11 11:25:05.000 [debug] circuit_remove_handled_ports(): Port 443 is not handled.
Jul 11 11:25:05.000 [info] circuit_predict_and_launch_new(): Have 0 clean circs (0 internal), need another exit circ.
Jul 11 11:25:06.000 [debug] circuit_remove_handled_ports(): Port 443 is not handled.
Jul 11 11:25:06.000 [info] circuit_predict_and_launch_new(): Have 0 clean circs (0 internal), need another exit circ.
Jul 11 11:25:07.000 [debug] circuit_remove_handled_ports(): Port 443 is not handled.
Jul 11 11:25:07.000 [info] circuit_predict_and_launch_new(): Have 0 clean circs (0 internal), need another exit circ.
Jul 11 11:25:08.000 [debug] circuit_remove_handled_ports(): Port 443 is not handled.
Jul 11 11:25:08.000 [info] circuit_predict_and_launch_new(): Have 0 clean circs (0 internal), need another exit circ.
```

I've installed Tor bundle from official Tor repo. What have I to do to prevent this error?